# Can't remove text-decoration?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, text-decorations

I can't remove text decoration from my website, precisely on two places: my site title, and on Contact Page.

I tried to do it with classes, I also copied CSS path from Inspect element mode in Opera and transfered it and modified it into wordpress editor.

But nothing happend. Also tried to do it with all `<a>` tags using `a{}` in CSS.

Some help would be nice. Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the text-decoration has been removed, but there is a border-bottom: 1px dotted #333 applied to the site title and the social media icons on the contact page. Are you confusing the two?

If you remove the border-bottom, the dotted line styling goes away.

Answer (score 0):

It is not text decoration what is making your site like this. It is border. Add these lines to your stylesheet (in wordpress editor):

```
.site-title a {
  border: 0;
}
```

If you also want to remove (under)line from social networks add this:

```
.drustvenemreze a {
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `text-decoration:none` set in your CSS for `<a>` tags, but you also have a `border-bottom: 1px dotted #333;`

I believe that is what is making it appear that the links you reference still have text-decoration applied. If you get rid of the border-bottom, you should be good.